# convert multiple svgs to xml in android studio at once

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have 100 svg files. If i go for traditional way to import svgs in the android studio it will take a very long time. https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ is deprecated. is there any new online converter available in the market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is detail steps:

1. Put all your svg files into a directory.
2. Download this jar file [from here](http://github.com/ravibhojwani86/Svg2VectorAndroid/blob/master/Svg2VectorAndroid-1.0.jar)
3. Copy the jar file to jdk bin directory. for mine it is(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin)
4. Open cmd on bin directory
5. run this command `java -jar Svg2VectorAndroid-1.0.jar your_svg_file_directory_path`
6. A new directory called processedSVG will be generated on your svg directory. There you will find your XML files.

Answer (score 4):

Just enter the **Resource Manager** as shown below, and **drag&drop**:

[image]

No need to use any external tools.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 1 + Windows 11: doesn't work :((((( Fu****

Answer (score 1):

actually there is a tool for this [converter](https://github.com/joelbrostrom/svg-to-vector-drawable)

but importing my 870 svg files for my current app took me about 10 minutes in android studio, the tool should reduce this overhead a bit. if its still too long you could split this task on more machines

Comment: I am new. how to use this converter. please tell me

Comment: its just a jar, you have to call it from commandline via ```java -jar converter.jar <path to svg dir>``` beware of windows or linux commandline syntax